# How to fix nullreferenceexception?

Tags: c#, loops, collections, nullreferenceexception

I am beginner programmer and I have problem in this code. When I run the code, it stuck at

```
monthly[i].ID = Console.ReadLine();
```

The error says : system.nullreferenceexception 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
At this program I have class MonthlyEmployee and DailyEmployee which inheritance of Employee. I want to access the properties with looping (do while). So, I add this outside the looping.

```
MonthlyEmployee[] monthly = new MonthlyEmployee[10];
List<Employee> listemployee = new List<Employee>();
```

How I can fix this? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Scroll to the section `Array Elements` of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/12833205.

Comment: Initialise `monthly[i] = new MonthlyEmployee()` and then use `monthly[i].ID = Console.ReadLine();`